# $q = a*\sqrt{b-cp^2}$ Find where the demand is elastic?

Tags: calculus, economics

The demand equation for a manufacturer's product has the form $ q = a*\sqrt{b-cp^2}$. Where, a, b, and c are positive integers.

a) Determine the interval of prices for which demand is elastic.

b) For which price is there unit elasticity?

Notes: Elasticity formula: $$\frac{p}{q} * \frac{dq}{dp} $$

and it is elastic when the above formula bigger than 1 and unit elastic when it is equal to one.

So, I took the derivative of q to find the right side of the formula and I got:
$$\frac{-acp}{\sqrt{b-cp^2}}$$ Then I wrote the left hand side of the formula as $$\frac{p}{a\sqrt{b-cp^2}}$$. And when I multiplied the left hand side with right hand side I got $$\frac{-cp^2}{b-cp^2}.$$

So now I need to find the intervals for p when this expression is bigger than 1 but if you try to solve the inequality only thing you left is 0 > b.

I don't know where I went wrong. Please explain it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you got it right. You get $0>b$ so there is no $p$ for which the demand is elastic. Calculus at least is alright, unless the given formula is wrong for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively Elastic is when $E_d\lt -1$

Hence $$\frac{-cp^2}{b-cp^2}\lt -1$$
$$cp^2\gt b-cp^2$$

$$2cp^2 \gt b$$

$$p^2\gt \frac{b}{2c}$$

Elastic when $p\gt \sqrt{\frac{b}{2c}}$ and $p\lt -\sqrt{\frac{b}{2c}}$

Unit Elastic when $p= \sqrt{\frac{b}{2c}}$

Comment: Isn't it elastic when $E_d$ > 1  as oppose to $E_d\lt -1$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ Price_elasticity_of_demand, last few paragraphs lists you the condition of elasticity

Comment: Ok I checked my formula from lecture slides and it is not the E > 1 it is the absolute value of E > 1 so yeah it also makes E < -1. Thank you so much Satish.